# File write error in python

Tags: python

I tried to execute a command using pexpect module and directed the result to a text file.

While appending the text it includes some weird characters in the text file.

This occurs when i tried to use ctrl command in the python script.

Here is the text appended to the file (See Bold char). Please provide me a solution.

**[1m** configPortConnection ........ **[0m**< slot connectMode >

**[1m** cpldReg ..................... **[0m**< op address data >

***Actual text should be like this:***

configPortConnection ........ < slot connectMode >

cpldReg ..................... < op address data >

Thanks

Comment: Those are escape codes, probably for coloring text in the console.

Comment: How can I remove those codes when I append text to a file?

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693701/how-can-i-remove-the-ansi-escape-sequences-from-a-string-in-python or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506033/filtering-out-ansi-escape-sequences, or even http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4527/program-that-passes-stdin-to-stdout-with-color-codes-stripped. These are all various ways to strip ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: What command are you executing? It might be possible to turn off colour codes, e.g. for `grep` there is the `--color=never` option.