# parsing data tagged with ANSI color escape sequences

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-parsing

need help with converting a log file with data tagged with ANSI color escape sequences and date time stamps. Here is the format for lines in the text:

```
'\x1b[34m[SOME_INFO]\x1b[0m \x1b[36m[SOME_OTHR_INFO]\x1b[0m Thu Sep 09 00:59:12 XST some variable length message which might contain commas (,), etc.'
```

I am on an isolated network with almost no access to Internet and using Python 2.7.

I have wasted a few hours :(. The closest I got to is using @Elliot Chance's solution

```
re.sub(r'\x1b\[[\d;]+m', '', s)
```

provided here [Filtering out ANSI escape sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506033/filtering-out-ansi-escape-sequences) as follows:

```
t = re.sub(r'\x1b\[[\d;]+m', '~', s)
re.split(r'~|(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun.*?\d{4})', t)
```

which doesn't give me what I want. 
The output from above code:

```
['',
 None,
 '[SOME_INFO]',
 None,
 ' ',
 None,
 '[SOME_OTHR_INFO]',
 None,
 ' ',
 'Thu',
 ' Sep 09 00:59:12 XST some variable length message which might contain commas (,), etc.']
```

The output I am looking for is as follows:

```
'SOME_INFO, SOME_OTHR_INFO, Thu Sep 09 00:59:12 XST, some variable length message which might contain commas (,), etc.
```

Is there a way to load the data to a pandas dataframe using `pandas.read_csv()` or similar?

Note: Every line starts with an escape code but there could be variable fields in each line (i.e., 
`SOME_INFO, SOME_OTHR_INFO, ANOTHER_INFO, etc. followed by the timestamp followed by free text).`

Comment: As i understand, you want to remove the ***"escape sequences"*** only? So simple replace it with a empty string `''` using [re.Pattern.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.sub)

Comment: In the output you're looking for, `SOME_INFO` no longer has square brackets, even though the brackets weren't part of an ANSI escape sequence? What's the logic for removing them?

Comment: @stovfl, the idea is to convert this data into CSVs. I can replace the escape sequences with anyother string but that doesn't solve all of my problems.

Comment: @Grismar, I can leave the brackets its not a major problem but just wanted to remove them to have clean data. I guess the brackets are just the artefact of the logging process.

Comment: @Kam: ***"Every line starts with an escape"***: So replace with `'\n'` instead of `''`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following did the job for me:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

def split_line(s):
    t = re.sub(r'\x1b\[[\d]+m', '~', s) #assume ~ is not present in the free text field 
    t = re.sub('~\s+~|~\s+), '~', s)
    return filter(None, re.split('~|(\D{3}\s\D{3}\s\d{2}.*\d{4})\s+', t))
```

Next steps:

- Read the file into a single column dataframe using

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None, sep='\n', engine='python', index_col=False)
```

- Apply the above function to each row of the dataframe above. I had trouble applying the `pd.apply()` so I ended up using the list comprehension method instead

```
col_names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df = pd.DataFrame([split_line(str(s)) for s in df[0], columns=col_names]
df.head()
```

- Finally write the file to a csv using `df.to_csv()`